# Low latency audio capture with gstreamer

Tags: audio, gstreamer, low-latency

I need (almost) real-time audio capturing on Linux with `gstreamer`. My problem is that I cannot reduce the latency below ~210ms. I tried a simple loopback from mic to headphone:

```
gst-launch-1.0 pulsesrc ! alsasink
gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc ! alsasink
```

Both produced the same delay. The `latency-time` property of `alsasrc` did not help (it did add the given latency). I could produce the effect I need with

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
```

But I could not figure out whether it is possible to set the device latency for the `pulsesrc` plug-in of `gstreamer`. I guess, if it is possible, I should add something to the `stream-properties`, but could not figure out what ([I searched for it here](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/pulseaudio/doxygen/proplist_8h.html)) and how.

Is it possible to set this device latency for any `gstreamer` sources, and if yes, how?

Comment: some of these audio libraries ( jack ) offer a real-time option during install ... did you see such an option ? ... its not the default as it transfers priority over to audio processing to the detriment of non-audio processes

Comment: Maybe you want to test the latency at the ALSA level and see if this is maybe more of an ALSA question than a GStreamer one?  http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Test_latency.c

Comment: I see also that there's a `buffer-time` property on alsasrc that you may want to try.  The default value is 200000 microseconds which looks suspiciously like the latency you're seeing..

Comment: I'm sure that the system is able to work low-latency, as the `pactl` worked and the alsa latency test prog also reports about 2ms latencies. But neither setting the `buffer-time` (I've also found it earlier) or `latency-time` alsasrc properties have the desired effect. (With low `buffer-time` the loopback sound starts glitching, and the `latency-time` can increase but cannot reduce the latency.)

Comment: look like gstreamer have too much delay. I actually confirmed that pulse audio have 1ms delay but the best that gstreamer provide is 100ms

Answer (score 2):

Using pulsesink instead of alsasink may solve the problem. Try this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v alsasrc buffer-time=35000 !  pulsesink
```

Answer (score 0):

About as close as you can get to zero latency over network is about 20ms.  This example produces the same RTP stream as you would get from a VoIP call with max ptime of 20 in the Session Description protocol.  The first pipeline is the speaker and the second pipeline is the listener.  I haven't tested this with lower latencies or to a local sink pad for that matter, but the setting does exist for your purpose.

## speaker

```
gst-launch alsasrc name=mic provide-clock=true actual-buffer-time=20000 do-timestamp=true buffer-time=20000 \
mic. \
! alawenc \
! rtppcmapay max-ptime=20000000 \
! udpsink host=192.168.1.2 port=5000
```

## listener

```
gst-launch udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)8000, encoding-name=(string)PCMA" \
! rtppcmadepay \
! audio/x-alaw, rate=8000, channels=1 \
! alawdec \
! alsasink buffer-time=80000
```